# Proxy settings for urllib.urlretrieve

Tags: python, proxy, ftp, urllib

I am using `urllib.urlretrieve` to download a file on a remote FTP site with the anonymous pattern.

[ftp://ftp.{DOMAIN}/register/{FOLDER1}/{FOLDER2}/{FOLDER3}/{FILE}](ftp://ftp.%7BDOMAIN%7D/register/%7BFOLDER1%7D/%7BFOLDER2%7D/%7BFOLDER3%7D/%7BFILE%7D)

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve(FILE_TO_DOWNLOAD, DESTINATION_FILE)
```

When it was run on my company computer, it gave me an error as below:

```
IOError: [Errno ftp error] proxy support for ftp protocol currently not implemented
```

I know it lacks of proxy settings in the code, but I have no idea where and how to set up my proxy settings.

Answer (score 2):

How to set up proxies:

**Python 2.7.10**

Pass into urlopen with proxy. See documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html):

```
# Use http://www.someproxy.com:3128 for http proxying
proxies = {'http': 'http://www.someproxy.com:3128'}
filehandle = urllib.urlopen(some_url, proxies=proxies)
```

Or, set the `http_proxy` environmental variable before starting the python interpreter.

```
% http_proxy="http://www.someproxy.com:3128"
% export http_proxy
% python
```

**Python 3.5**

This is right from the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request).

```
import urllib.request
proxies = {'http': 'http://proxy.example.com:8080/'}
opener = urllib.request.FancyURLopener(proxies)
with opener.open("http://www.python.org") as f:
f.read().decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: This does not work due to the firewall settings in my company. :(

Comment: this looks like it's opening a site, not downloading a file (ie. `urllib.request.urlretrieve`)